# Series convergence: bound needed

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Why should the following series converge? Can't find a good bound

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\exp{\left( -\frac{n^{1-\alpha}}{\sqrt{\log{n}}}\right)}}$$ for $\alpha<1$

Comment: @Dr.MV The inequality in your first comment implies that the sum of the series is at least $\sum\limits_n\exp(-n^{1-\alpha})$. Then what? More promising is to note that $n^{1-\alpha}/(\log n)^{1/2}>n^\beta$ for some suitable positive $\beta$, for every $n$ large enough.

Comment: @Did You're absolutely correct.  I had chemo yesterday and goofed on the direction of the inequality.  Yes, the intention was to reduce the problem as you suggested.  Thank you for the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By L'Hospital's rule, it is easily seen that
$$
2\log^{3/2}{n}=o(n^{\epsilon})
$$
where $\epsilon>0$. So for large $n>N$
$$
2\log{n}<\frac{n^{\epsilon}}{\log^{1/2}{n}}
$$
And 
$$
\exp\left(-\frac{n^{\epsilon}}{\log^{1/2}{n}}\right)<\exp\left(-2\log{n}\right)=\frac1{n^2}
$$
So 
$$
\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{n^{\epsilon}}{\log^{1/2}{n}}\right)<\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac1{n^2}<\infty
$$

Comment: Smart. $\frac{\ln^a n}{n^\epsilon}=\left(\frac{\ln n}{n^{\epsilon/a}}\right)^a\to 0$ for $a>0$ can be also seen without L'Hospital.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the term with $n=0$ because it contains $1/ \log 1 =1/0$.... We have  $\lim _{m \to \infty}  ( \log m )/m=0$, so for fixed  $b > 0$  we have $0 < (\log m)/m < 2b$  for all sufficiently large $m$, so  for all sufficiently large $n$ we have $0 < (\log n^{2b})/n^{2b} < 2b$, equivalently, $0 < \sqrt {\log n} < n^b$.  So let $0 < b < 1- \alpha$ and let $c=1- \alpha -b$. ( Note $c > 0$.)   For sufficiently large $n$ we have $$n^{1-\alpha}/\sqrt {\log n} > n^c $$ so $$0 < \text{exp}(-n^{1-\alpha}/\sqrt {\log n}) <  \text{exp}(-n^c).$$ Now the function $f(n)= \exp {(-n^c)}$ for $n \in N$ is decreasing and positive and so is the continuous function  $g(x)=\exp {(-x^c)}$ for $x  > 1$, while $f(n)=g(n)$ for $n \in N$.Thus we may use the integral test: If $$J=\int_{x=2}^\infty g(x)dx < \infty$$ then the summation  $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \exp(-n^c)$ is finite.Make a change of variable: $x=y^c$, so $$J= \int_{y=d}^\infty (cy^{1-1/c}\exp y)^{-1}  dy$$ where $d=2^{1/c} > 0$ .Now choose $k \in N$ with $k+1-1/c > 2$. We have $\exp y > y^k/k!$ for all positive $y$ so $$J <
\int_d^\infty k!/(cy^2) dy < \infty$$ so the series converges.